# Hard Disk Spins Down as long as Battery is in Laptop

Tags: 10.04, power-management

I just figured out today that as long as the battery is in my laptop, it doesn't matter if it's fully charged while plugged in, Ubuntu always spins down my hard drive. I noticed this because there was a huge difference in speed when I removed the batteries.

My settings for power management is basically:

- on AC power, don't spin down
  harddrive, dont suspend or anything
- on battery power, basically save as
  much power as possible

I assumed that if I plug in my laptop, it'll use the On AC Power settings no matter what but apparently, this isn't so. Is there a way to "fix" this?

Comment: the slow down on battery power makes no sense to me (if it is the hdd spinning down). I personally think you might have another problem.

Comment: well, if I uncheck the "spin down hdd when possible" in the On Battery option, it works so much faster.

Comment: You should file a bug report, please check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs .

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try editing these settings in gconf-editor:

```
gconf-editor /apps/gnome-power-manager/disks
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to eliminate if you have a battery problem. If you remove the battery and just run on the charger and the problem goes away it could be a battery that is pulling too much current and the system would go bonkers because the little external charger can't handle the load. You can check the battery by giving it a full charge then run on battery in Windows if you have Dual boot or a live CD other than Ubuntu. If you still have the problem it is probably the battery. If not it's likely a software problem. Good luck.  Maury